# How to align only three items per row

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some trouble accurately displaying a maximum of three items per row. This is the bit that I need to modify, but I just can't see how a variable like `$count` can be used to determine the number of rows needed and how to also align them accurately.

This is what it currently looks like:
[image]

This is the code:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        print

        "<div id='products' class='row list-group'>".
        "<div class='item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4'>".
            "<div class='thumbnail'>".
                "<img class='group list-group-image' alt='' />".
                "<div class='caption'>".
                    "<h4 class='group inner list-group-item-heading'>
                        'Title 1'</h4>".
                    "<p class='group inner list-group-item-text'>
                        Sample.</p>".
                    "<div class='row'>".
                        "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>".
                            "<p class='lead'>
                                654</p>".
                        "</div>".
                        "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>".
                            "<input type='submit' value='Add to basket'  class='btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg'  >".
                        "</div>".
                    "</div>".
                "</div>".
            "</div>".
        "</div>";
    }
}
```

Somewhere in there I don't know how to determine how to accurately split it.

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: After trying the code below I am now getting something like this:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: are the elements displayed in different rows?

Comment: Hi, I posted a picture in the original post. I wasn't sure how to explain it but  as you can see in the picture, they are not aligned properly

Comment: I suspect theres a disconnect between the code you've posted and the first image. The first image shows `";` printed for each of the items (appears to be unparsed PHP and probably causing the problem.) - but that doesn't show up anywhere in your code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    print "<div id='products'>";
    $count = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
       if ($count % 3 === 0) {
          if ($count > 0) print "</div>";
          print "<div class='row list-group'>";
       }
        print
        "<div class='item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4'>".
            "<div class='thumbnail'>".
                "<img class='group list-group-image' alt='' />".
                "<div class='caption'>".
                    "<h4 class='group inner list-group-item-heading'>
                        'Title 1'</h4>".
                    "<p class='group inner list-group-item-text'>
                        Sample.</p>".
                    "<div class='row'>".
                        "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>".
                            "<p class='lead'>
                                654</p>".
                        "</div>".
                        "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>".
                            "<input type='submit' value='Add to basket'  class='btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg'  >".
                        "</div>".
                    "</div>".
                "</div>".
            "</div>".
        "</div>";
       $count++;
    }
    print "</div>".
     "</div>";
}
```

Notes:

- You shouldn't print the same ID more than once
- You were printing a "row" multiple times instead of just items within the row

The other post was on the right track in using the $count % 3 === 0 statement up top, but we should both both open a new div, AND close the last div there (if it isn't the first iteration).
After the loop, we always close the row.list-group div, for it will always be open by our design.

Comment: IT WORKED! THANKS :)